# How to add tag name and value to NSMutableDictionary using NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, parsing, xml-parsing, nsmutabledictionary

What I'm trying to achieve is to say, having an XML structure like this:

```
<parent>
  <nodename1>NodeText1</nodename1>
  <nodename2>NodeText2</nodename2>
  ...
  <nodenamex>NodeTextx</nodenamex>
</parent>
```

And upon parsing, set it into an NSMutableDictionary into key=>value pairs where key is the nodename and the value is nodetext. However, I have no idea how to link them both because, if I understand correctly, the nodename is recognized in `didStartElement` and nodetext gets picked up in `foundCharacters`, right? Does anyone know how to do this? I can post the code I have so far but it's pretty basic.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not to use GDataXML? It has a great performance and it is easy to use. For a tutorial see [how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the didStartElement method, when you identify node name as "parent", create a dictionary.
In found characters, store the value in string object.
In didEndElement method, if string value (you have in foundcharacters) is not null then add into a dictionary with key as element name. Now, release the string value and assigned it to nil.